# How to share screen between Centos 7 and Ubuntu 14?

Tags: ubuntu, centos

I am using *Remina Remote Desktop Client* to share screen between ubuntu machines. But I did not find Remina in centos.

Answer (score 0):

You may find suitable [RPM package online](https://centos.pkgs.org/6/russian-fedora-free-i386/remmina-0.9.3-5.el6.R.i686.rpm.html), build it from source code should work too.

Also it's easier with [VNC server](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server), which is officially supported by centos.

Answer (score 0):

Just build *TeamViewer* from source or use *VNC*.